# Adding padding to a textarea pushes the element outside of the div

Tags: html, css, textarea

I can't seem to be able to wrap my mind around this one.

It seems that by adding some padding (padding-left: 3px) to my textarea, and it pushes it right out of my div with the border. Adding some padding for text inside the summary box would be useful as it would be more legible to the user.

Here is the result:[image]

This is what it should look like:
[image]

Here is the HTML / CSS markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
.fcontent_text {
    font-size: 8.5pt;
    text-align: right;
    color: rgb(11,63,113);
}
#fcontent_container {
    width: 800px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
}
#fcontent_wrapper {
    border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
}
#summary {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3px;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
                <div id="fcontent_container">
                    <div class="fcontent_text">Summary</div>
                    <div id="fcontent_wrapper"><textarea class="normal" id="summary"></textarea></div>
                </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't have `width: 100%` and left or right padding - that's why you're spilling over the edges of the container.

Answer (score 15):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to `#summary` so that you can set both `width: 100%` and left and right padding without the contents spilling over into the container.

> ## [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
>
> `border-box`
>
> - The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode.

For cross-browser compatibility, be sure to include prefixes:

```
#summary {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 3px;
    height: 50px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using box-sizing**
You can use `box-sizing: border-box;`
Check this out: http://codepen.io/gopkar/pen/HiEjn

**Without box-sizing**
Change the width of your textarea from `width: 100%` to `width: 795px;`
Have a look at http://codepen.io/gopkar/pen/csxKo
`width = <div-width> - <padding-you-have-given>`

Comment: In order to use `795px`, I had to remove other default padding from the `<textarea>`: `padding: 0px 0px 0px 3px;`.

Answer (score 1):

For some odd reason this solution seems to circumvent everything and works flawlessly:

```
<div style="width: 800px">
<div style="text-align: right;">Expand</div>
    <div style="padding-right: 6px;">
        <textarea style="width: 100%; padding: 2px; margin: 0; border : solid 1px #999"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```